# How to dynamically query my VSCode extension version from the extension code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm writing an extension for VSCode. I would like to get the runtime version of the extension from its own code. Is there a way to do that?

I found `VSCode.extensions.getExtension('myExtensionId').packageJSON` but I don't know what to do with that.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/66856807/836330 for some updated info on getting the extension version and other info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the version in the activate function:

`context.extension.packageJSON.version`

where `context` is the ExtensionContext parameter from the activate function

Answer (score 8):

I was finally close. Using:

```
VSCode.extensions.getExtension('publisher.myExtensionId').packageJSON.version
```

seems to do the trick.

Comment: make sure to also check for undefined: `VSCode.extensions.getExtension('publisher.myExtensionId')!.packageJSON.version`

Comment: Is it possible to get pass versions as well?

Answer (score 1):

When the extension is activated, the current extension context is passed as argument. You may use the context.extensionPath instead of hardcoded extension id string 'publisher.myExtensionId'.

```js
import * as Path from 'path';
import * as fs from 'fs';

export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
    var extensionPath = Path.join(context.extensionPath, "package.json");
    var packageFile = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(extensionPath, 'utf8'));

    if (packageFile) {
        console.log(packageFile.version);
    }

//......... rest

}
```