# How can I get the latest version number in my vscode extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

when my vscode extension is updated,  Show an information message to users。
ps：How can I get the latest version number  in my vscode extension?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63970169/9938317

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the extension version and other info, see

> #### Extension property on ExtensionContext menu
>
> Extension authors can now use the new `extension` property on
> `ExtensionContext`, which is passed into the extension's `activate`
> function. This returns the same `Extension` instance that
> `vscode.extensions.getExtension(<extension-id>)` returns, which
> contains properties such as, the extension's id, version, as well as a
> serialized `packageJSON` property where you can access data directly
> from your extension's `package.json` file.

from [v1.55 release notes](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_55.md#extension-property-on-extensioncontext-menu)

Answer (score 0):

VS Code updates extensions automatically by default, it should not be necessary to manually check the versions of installed extensions.
This site might be helpful as well, official VS Code docs
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-gallery#_extension-autoupdate

Comment: Thanks  for your help.  However，VS Code just updates extensions automatically ,Unless I search this extension.  and I want to display some information  to users ,when there is  a new version of my  extension.